# How do you append modified data from a for loop? (Python)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, python-3.x, append

Thanks for checking out my question, am using Python 3 by the way, here is the code:)

```
scale=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
MNP = {'scale degree' : []
}


 for index, value in enumerate(scale):

    scale.insert(len(scale),scale[0])
    del scale[0]
    MNP['scale degree'].append(scale[1])
    print (MNP['scale degree'])
```

So, my goal here is append the modified versions of a list I called scale, into a dict I called MNP. *The desired output is a list ('scale degree' that takes the original number of a list (such as scale), and moves it the end of the list, at the same time, all the numbers would shift one to the left, this is what is happens if I give the command to print the scale within the function:*

```
for index, value in enumerate(scale):

    scale.insert(len(scale),scale[0])
    del scale[0]
    MNP['scale degree'].append(scale[1])
    print (MNP['scale degree'])

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
[5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Yet when I try to do so I encountered (yes, past tense) a problem with my understanding. See, if I execute the command:

```
    print(scale[1])
```

Then it actually ***does*** print the numbers 2,3,4,5,6,1 . This is why I used the enumerate function, I thought that this may solve the problem. I thought that, maybe the index number determined somehow ***which list*** would be printed off, but this is of course is wrong, even though the output is identical, and, it's worth mentioning that am still very much a stargazed newbie. Yet I did some thinking and realized that it's merely printing off the second value of each modified list, the exact same as if I gave it a single command to print off only one version, yet being a disobedient little bugger if I ask it to append the whole blown thing.

Bloody Hell.

So, now, my question is, how do I append the modified version of the scale, and not just a single value?

Appending the scale as a whole does'st work by the way (this was also my first solution), as the output is then:
    [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]]
    [[3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]]
    [[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]]

it keeps going in this fashion until it reaches [1,2,3,4,5,6] * 6

Thanks in advance for any help, also if you may, could you recommend resources so that I can gain a basic understanding of what's playing behind the scenes?  There's probably a lot I still don't understand (I mean in relation only to this problem alone, of course, in general am *that* close to understanding everything there is to know (haha)).

Thanks again

- James

P.S how long in general should I wait till I seek help on SE? (For this particular problem, I've been dueling with if for a solid Day 1/2)

P.S.S  A thanks to Borodin for pointing that the manipulation of data within a for loop is bad practice. How should this be correctly executed?

Comment: Cut it back a ways: what is it you're trying to do here?

Comment: What do you want the contents of `MNP['scale degree']` to be after the `for` loop?

Comment: You shouldn't modify a list while you're iterating through it. It's just going to cause problems.

Comment: Hey guys, i'll put it in the description, thanks for the feedback

Comment: You're not appending the whole of `scale` anywhere. The statement `MNP['scale degree'].append(scale[1])` appends just `scale[1]` - the second element. If you want to append all of the contents of `scale` then you should use `append(scale)` or `extend(scale)` depending on the effect you want.

Comment: Hey Borodin, yeah, I know exactly what you mean, but if I try this then the results aren't as you'd expect, the output is in the question' though you never saw that since i've only just edited it.

This was actually my first solution by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the effect you're after?

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l.append(my_list.pop())
[2,3,4,1]
```

Or if you want it unrolled a little:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> e = my_list.pop()
>>> l.append(e)
[2,3,4,1]
```

In both cases, we remove the first element from the list and stick it on the end of the list - which I think is what you're after.

Or if you don't want to modify the original list:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l[1:]+[l[0]]    
[2,3,4,1]
```

Here, we're just recombining slices - the original list is unchanged. Notice that I have to put l[0] into a list because that's the way + is implemented for lists - I can't do l[1:] + l[0].

Comment: Do you mean like this?

    scale=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    MNP = {'scale degree' : []
                  }

    for i in(scale):
        scale.append(MNP['scale degree'].pop())
        print (MNP['scale degree'])

Comment: No, I mean what I said. If you want a circular left shift, this is among the easiest ways to do it. You don't need a loop.

Comment: Ah, like this?

scale.append(scale.pop(0))


Also, sorry for the messy can't, it wont format in the way that it does when posting a Q

Comment: Yeah, like that. Or see my latest edit for a nondestructive approach, in case you don't want to modify `scale`.

Comment: Hi, thanks, it works! is there a way to do this multiple times however, should I use a loop?

Comment: Well, for example you could do `l[i:]+l[:i]` to generalize the non-destructive approach to "rotate left by i places"

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) would help. It has `rotate(n)` which shifts the elements of the list by `n` places.

```
import collections
my_list = []
d = collections.deque([1,2,3,4,5])
for i in range(5):
    d.rotate(-1)
    my_list.append(d)
print my_list
```

Output:

```
[deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]
```

Comment: Thankyou, but (yeeeah, i know), it only works for the first rotation, after that somthing weird happens:

   `scale=collections.deque([1,2,3,4,5])

    MNP = {'scale degree' : []
                  }
    for i in range(5):
        scale.rotate(-i)
        print (scale)


    >>>deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    >>>deque([2, 3, 4, 5, 1])
    >>>deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3])
    >>>deque([2, 3, 4, 5, 1])
    >>>deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`

Comment: How many times you wish to rotate ? "something weird happens" like what ?

Comment: It seems to rotate the first digit to the end as expected, though then it rotates the first and second digits afterwards, and then the first 3 etc.

Comment: Ah damn, there's still a minor problem, I cant append the results to another list, is there a way to do this?